# Metaplex: Mint standard Edition

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I was wondering how to *mint* an [NFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token#Description) with Metaplex without doing MasterEdition. I want to do a simple edit with a supply of 1.

But in the Metaplex program, you have to call "CreateMasterEdition" and give the MaxSupply. And then call "MintNewEditionFromMasterEdition". However, when I go to Solsea for example and I mint an NFT, I don't have a master edition, but a simple edition.

Is it possible to mint a single edition directly?
Do marketplaces, such as Solsea, mint a master edition, then create an edition from it and keep or burn the MasterEdition? I would like to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, according to the Metaplex documentation to make a "single" edition, I must create a MasterEdition with a supply of 0.

> The existence of Metadata and its sister PDA MasterEdition makes a very powerful combination for a mint that enables the entire rest of the Metaplex contract stack. Now you can create:
>
> - Normal mints that just have names (Metadata but no MasterEdition)
> - **One of a kind NFTs (Metadata + MasterEdition with max_supply of 0)**
> - NFTs that can print limited edition child NFTs (Metadata + MasterEdition with max_supply of say 10)
> - NFTs that can print unlimited open edition NFTs (Metadata + MasterEdition with unlimited max_supply)

Answer (score 0):

A master edition serves as proof that the token is non-fungible.

In Solsea, the NFTs made don't have this information. The result is that when the token is viewed in explorer.solana, you have "No Master Information". The advantage of having that Master Edition is that, as I've mentioned, it serves as proof that the token is an NFT.

Here is [a Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/SolanaMBS/status/1494377432907931648) that talks about not having a Master Edition.

And [here](https://docs.solsea.io/getting-started/faq/nfts-non-fungible-tokens/create-mint#can-i-create-multiple-nfts-per-each-art-piece) is the only information I saw about editions in the Solsea documentation.

Comment: I do not really understand. An NFT is a 0 decimal Solana token while editing is only for metadata. How can metadata be used as proof?

From what I understand, the master edition is like "a mold" allowing to create several times the same artwork, it can be entrusted to a third party who will take care of the "production" and the sale (like a marketplace ).

For my project, I don't need this. I would just like to create an NFT, and have a signle edition. I would like to mint the token immediately and put it on the user's wallet.